# The typescript does not return data to the specified type on the axios request

Tags: typescript, axios

I requested data by Axios and specified the type. The requested data is well returned but not stored in the product array. How can I solve the problem?

```js
const response = await axios.get({products: Product[];}>('http://localhost:8000/api/product');
```

The product type is as follows:

```js
export interface Product {
   id: string;
   image: string;
   name: string;
   price: number;
}
```

Return data (example)

```
0: {id: "1", name: "skirt", image: "https://www.example.com", price: "₩590,000"}
...
```

The log output is as follows.

```
console.log(response.data);
console.log(products);
```

```
# response.data
0: {id: "1", name: "skirt", image: "https://www.example.com", price: "₩590,000"}
...

# products
[]
```

Comment: Where do you create the products variable?  It should be const products = response.data.products.  If that’s not right then the response isn’t what you think it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a syntax error on the `axios.get` line, it supposed to look like this

```
const response = await axios.get<Product[]>('http://localhost:8000/api/product');
```

You are passing a generic (`<Product[]>`) to `axios.get()` function to tell axios that the returned data (`response.data`) type will be `Product[]`, so your code will look like this:

```
const response = await axios.get<Product[]>('http://localhost:8000/api/product');

const products = response.data;

products; // Product[]
```